# Default parameters and currying: Python vs. Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, closures, currying

Consider the following problem: I want to create an array of functions, each function just prints its index in that array. In Python, it can be done easily with

```
funcs = []
for i in range(5):
   funcs.append(lambda i=i: print(i))
funcs[2]()
# 2
```

Here we use default argument values as a way to do currying (if I understand the term right).

Prior to ES6, there were no default argument values in Javascript, so currying had to be done in different way. Now we have them and I tried to translate Python to Javascript literally:

```
funcs = []
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   funcs.push(function (i=i) {console.log(i)})
}
# this part pass OK
funcs[2]()
ReferenceError: i is not defined
    at Array.<anonymous> (evalmachine.<anonymous>:3:27)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:9
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:26:33)
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:79:17)
    at run ([eval]:608:19)
    at onRunRequest ([eval]:379:22)
    at onMessage ([eval]:347:17)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at process.nextTick (internal/child_process.js:752:12)
```

Why it fails? What's the difference between Python and Javascript ways to pass default values?

(Okay, I know that I can use `let` here instead of `var`, I'm just studying Javascript after several years with Python and trying to understand it underhoods.)

Comment: Just use a different variable name, `j=i` then `console.log(j)`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with currying. This has to do with the late-binding of closures in Python. This is actually a hack that takes advantage of the fact that default arguments in Python are set at function definition time, letting you simulate early binding. Probably, there lies the differences with Javascript (which I believe also has late-binding closures).

Comment: @elclanrs changing the variable name simply exposes another issue, which is the closure created by the for loop, in which `funcs[n]` will always return the maximum value of `i`. Which is what juanpa.arrivillaga was alluding to with late vs simulated-early binding in closures.

Comment: You can use `let` instead of `var`

Comment: @elclanrs, I know this, see the last sentence of my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Javascript and Python using late-binding in closures. However, using a default argument is a hack that let's you simulate early binding in Python, and that works because default parameters are evaluated at **function definition time** in Python. However, in Javascript default arguments, according to the docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

> The default argument gets evaluated at call time, so unlike e.g. in
>   Python, a new object is created each time the function is called.

Here is one of the solutions used in Python that can be applied to this problem in Javascript. I've transliterated into Javascript the best I could. Essentially, define *another* anonymous function that returns your original, and apply it at the same time. This is very messy to my eyes, and in Python, I always go with the default-argument:

```
funcs = []
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    funcs.push((function (i) {return function() {console.log(i)}})(i))
};
funcs[0]() // 0
funcs[4]() // 4
```

In Python:

```
>>> funcs = []
>>> for i in range(5):
...     funcs.append((lambda i: lambda : print(i))())
...
>>> funcs[0]()
0
>>> funcs[4]()
4
```

I think it is clear that you should use `.bind` in Javascript, as elucidated in other answers, and not this clunky solution.

Comment: No need to nest functions, just use `.bind()` like so with an inline function `funcs.push((function (i) { console.log(i); }).bind(this, i));`

Comment: I agree you should use `.bind`, I am not a Javascript programmer, although I've tinkered around with it, and cannot comment on best practices, I just wanted to elucidate what was going on by virtue of comparing it with Python.

Answer (score 2):

Your issues have to do with the difference between *when* **default** parameters get bound in closures in python vs JavaScript. While it is true that both JavaScript and Python use late-binding, in the case of default parameters, Python simulates early-binding, whereas JavaScript does not.

That being said, if you are going to be creating closures like this, you may as well take advantage of them and ditch the parameters all together, honestly.

You mentioned the use of `let` and that is important if you want to define the function inside the for loop because otherwise `funcs[n]` will always be your maximum value of your iterator (due to the late-binding of JavaScript closures).

Try this:

```js
funcs = [];
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
   funcs.push(function () {console.log(i)});
}
funcs[2]();
```

Alternatively, if you want to follow good practice of not defining functions within a loop, you can define the function outside, and pass the variable in using `.bind()`. One thing to note is that this method will bind the variable with the value at the time `.bind()` is called, so you do not have to use `let`

```js
funcs = [];
function myFunc(i) {
  console.log(i);
}
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   funcs.push(myFunc.bind(this, i));
}
funcs[2]();
```

Comment: Just to be clear, binding of free variables is late in both Python and Javascript, however, there is a quirk in Python that default arguments are set at function definition time, allowing you to sidestep late-binding.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, I didn't make that very clear in my original post - I have updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate `.bind` solution. I'd like to accept this answer too if I could accept several answers…

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov The author of the answer you accepted said that my solution is the one that should be used lol

Answer (score 1):

If you use `let` instead of `var` you get a new binding for each iteration.

```
funcs = []
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  funcs.push(function (j=i) {console.log(j)})
}

funcs[2];//2
```

`i=i` doesn't work because in ES6  parameters can define defaults using other parameters

```
f = function(a=1, b=a){console.log(b);}
f() // 1
```

So the parser is getting confused.

Comment: Thanks, I really like the point on *`i=i` doesn't work because in ES6 parameters can define defaults using other parameters*. It answers my answer partially, it's a pity I cannot accept two answers simulatniously.